# Fetch data from multiple tables in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working on an application where I want to fetch the records from multiple tables which are connected through foreign key. The query I am using is

```
  select ue.institute, ue.marks, uf.relation, uf.name
  from user_education ue, user_family uf where ue.user_id=12 and uf.user_id=12
```

The result of the query is

[image: Result]

You can see the data is repeating in it. I only want a record one time. I want no repetition. I want something like this

```
T1                 T2

id|name|fid      id|descrip| fid
1 |A   |1         1|DA     | 1
2 |B   |1         2|DB     | 1
2 |B   |1
```

Result which I want:

```
Result:

id|name|fid|id|descrip| fid
1 |A   |1  |1|DA     | 1
2 |B   |1  |2|DB     | 1
2 |B   |1  |
```

The results fetched through your query

[image]

The total rows are 5

More Information

[image: Table 1]

[image: Table 2]

I want the rows of same `user_id` from both tables but you can see in T1 there are 3 rows and in T2 there are 2 rows. I do not want repetitions but also I want to fetch all the data on the basis of `user_id`

Table Schemas,s

[T1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JT4RE.png)
[T2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOKIr.png)

Comment: Can you please edit your question and remove the mysql tag?

Comment: Just to add a little advice. Try to use some coherent data, even for your own understanding; examples like `aaaa` and `aaa` are so confusing to say the least.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see why you would want that, but the solution could be to use the window function `row_number()`:

```
SELECT ue.institute, ue.marks, uf.relation, uf.name
FROM (SELECT institute, marks, row_number() OVER ()
      FROM user_education
      WHERE user_id=12) ue
   FULL OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT relation, name, row_number() OVER ()
      FROM user_family
      WHERE user_id=12) uf
   USING (row_number);
```

The result would be pretty meaningless though, as there is no ordering defined in the individual result sets.

Comment: It is not fetching all the records.

Comment: Prove it by sharing what you get!

Comment: That looks correct, like the example you wrote in your question, right?

Comment: As it is right but i give it as an example. But in real i have more records.

Comment: My answer refers to the query about which you asked your question. If you actually have a different query, the answer will also be different. But the answer explains the principle which you should be able to use with your real query.

Comment: Thinking about it some more, could it be that the two result sets have some connection that you want preserved and that you didn't tell about?

Comment: They both have the foreign key field of a table. But the remaining fields in the tables are different.

Comment: And is that relevant for your desired output?

Comment: Let me again edit my question it help you to understand it more clearly.

Comment: Thanks. Can you show the table definitions? Do you want only the rows with `user_id = 12`?

Comment: Yes i can also share it. Actually i am testing it by giving an hard code id. When the query will be build i will replace it the value directly coming from user.

Comment: I still don't get why my answer is not the one you want. "More records" doesn't explain it well enough. *Which* records are missing?